# How can I find out the used size of an umounted filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, ext4

Is there a way to find out the used size of an umounted filesystem?

I want to resize the ext4 `/` filesystem, so I boot into a live Lubuntu using a Lubuntu bootable flash drive. Since the `/` filesystem is not mounted, I don't know how much I can shrink  it.

Thanks.

Comment: I would use `gparted`, it is a graphical tool. I love command live, but I do this so infrequently. Graphical tools are good for infrequent jobs, and visualisation. Both of which apply here.

Answer (score 5):

For ext2/3/4 filesystems you could use `dumpe2fs` or `tune2fs -l` (from `e2fsprogs`) to get the total, used, and available block counts (among other properties) e.g.

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda5 | grep -i block
Block count:              3999755
Reserved block count:     199987
Free blocks:              3396721
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024
Blocks per group:         32768
Inode blocks per group:   509
Flex block group size:    16
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you make the output in human readable sizes (e.g. GB/MB)

Comment: For example `<<<'scale=1;(3396721)*4096/2^30' bc` to get it in GiB, and `<<<'scale=1;(3396721-199987)*4096/2^30' bc` to make it match approximately the output of `df -h` (`df` works only when mounted of course).